# Issue manipulating appended html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I saw some similar questions but still can't get it.

```
$(function () {
  var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();
  $.ajax({
       async: false,
       url: "../public/currentfile",                   
       dataType: 'json',
       method:'POST',
       data: {"_token": csrf},
       complete: function(data) {
            console.log(data.responseJSON); 
            var created_at = data.responseJSON['created_at'];
            var filesize = data.responseJSON['filesize'];
            var filename = data.responseJSON['filename'];
            var fileid = data.responseJSON['fileid'];
            $("#results .toBeSelected").prepend("<tr class='tabledata newdata'><td>" + fileid + "</td><td>" + filename + "</td><td>" + filesize + "</td><td>" + created_at + "</td></tr>");
       }                    
  });
});
```

This is the AJAX request that prepends the html. In a separate file i'm using a JS context menu. But what ever the user clicks from the context menu it does not affect the prepended html. How can I manipulate the new html element? I've read something about `.on()`.

The output HTML is a table row. When a user right-clicks the newly added table row this AJAX should execute:

```
function getImage(){
    var classElements = document.querySelectorAll("tr.ui-selected td.filename");
    var csrf = $('input[name=_token]').val();

    var result;
    result = classElements[0].innerHTML;
    $.ajax({
        async: true,                      
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '../public/selecteduserfiles',
        data: {filename: result, "_token": csrf},
        complete: function(response) {
            console.log(response.responseJSON);                  
            $("img.getImage").attr('src', response.responseJSON);                
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `I've read something about .on()` have you tried anything?

Comment: This example appears to be incomplete. Please provide all relevant code and the output HTML (as saved from the browser).

Comment: @gurvinder372 I can't understand know how to deal with .on()

Comment: `on()` is a method that allows you to bind an event directly to the current jQuery selection or, when using a second (filter) argument, to a group of descendants of that selection. In your example the ajax function will fire immediately after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a string, you can make a DOM object with all properties and attributes you need and then append/prepend them:

```
var domObj = $('<tr/>')
                 .addClass('tabledata newdata')
                 .append('<td>" + fileid + "</td><td>" + filename + "</td><td>" + filesize + "</td><td>" + created_at + "</td>')
                 .on('click', function() { /* do something */ });
$("#results .toBeSelected").prepend(domObj);
```

Comment: Neater perhaps, but does not appear to have anything to do with the problem they are having. Their code will append "something".

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie It will append a new tr in a table.

Comment: This works. Tell me what is the problem, but this works.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It preprends: `" + fileid + "` `" + filename + "`  `" + filesize + "`

Answer (score 0):

The **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** is called event delegation.

> Description: Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

If you want to attach click event to the new elements added by javascript then you deal with fresh DOM and you should use event delegation.

Example bellow attach click event to the new row with class `tabledata` :

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".tabledata", function() {
    //Your code here
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That method is correct, but overloads the browsers proccesor, because browser search in all DOM structure everytime (since body to the matched selector), so in terms of performance that's not a good idea. It works perfectly however